# Is it the property "be unbounded" upwards absulote?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinity, forcing

I'm reading the paper [Cardinal invariants above the continuum](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729500003Y) by J. Cummings and S. Shelah. There they have de following lemma:

[image: Lemma 5]

I have a doubt about with the yellow part: what they really means with that? Because it is well know that every poset that adds a dominating real (e.g Hechler forcing) destroys every unbounded set of $(\omega^\omega,\leq^*)$ in the ground model.

I apreciate any aclaration about this point.

Comment: I believe $B$ here is a subset of $\mathbb{P}$, and the relevant notion of "unbounded" refers only to elements of $\mathbb{P}$; see Definition $1$.

Comment: @NoahScheweber if I understand you, are you saying that $V[G]$ is a P-extension?

Comment: No, $V[G]$ might not be a $\mathbb{P}$-extension. My point is that $\mathbb{P}$ itself is a fixed object - it doesn't change between $V$ and $V[G]$. In particular, if $B\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is unbounded in $V$ it remains unbounded in $V[G]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unbounded set" here means "unbounded *subset of $\mathbb{P}$*" - see Definition $1$. This definition only makes use of quantification over *elements* of $\mathbb{P}$, and so is absolute between $V$ and $W$ for any extension $W$.

(Note that it's crucial that we're working here with a poset and subset of that poset as opposed to *a definition of* a poset and subset. Actual sets don't change between extensions, but definitions can.)